# Filtering by values

Tags: sql

I wrote a query a few days ago to determine whether a software is installed on a computer or not but I'm having troubles with filtering it showing only the "NO" values.

Would appreciate any help, thanks

```
Select Distinct Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetName,
  tsysOS.OSname,
  Case
    When soft01.AssetID Is Null Then 'NO'
    Else 'YES'
  End As Avecto,
  Case
    When soft02.AssetID Is Null Then 'NO'
    Else 'YES'
  End As CrowdStrike,
  Case
    When soft03.AssetID Is Null Then 'NO'
    Else 'YES'
  End As Cortex,
  tblAssets.Firstseen,
  tblAssets.Lastseen
From tblAssets
  Left Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
  Left Join tsysOS On tsysOS.OScode = tblAssets.OScode
  Left Join (Select tblSoftware.AssetID
      From tblSoftware
        Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftwareUni.SoftID = tblSoftware.softID
      Where tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Like '%Avecto%') As soft01 On
    soft01.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Left Join (Select tblSoftware.AssetID
      From tblSoftware
        Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftwareUni.SoftID = tblSoftware.softID
      Where tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Like '%CrowdStrike%') As soft02 On
    soft02.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
  Left Join (Select tblSoftware.AssetID
      From tblSoftware
        Inner Join tblSoftwareUni On tblSoftwareUni.SoftID = tblSoftware.softID
      Where (tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Like '%Cortex%' Or
          tblSoftwareUni.softwareName Like '%XDR%')) As soft03 On
    soft03.AssetID = tblAssets.AssetID
Where tsysOS.OSname Like '%Win 20%'
Order By tblAssets.AssetName
```

Comment: try this where clause - "Where tsysOS.OSname Like '%Win 20%' and (soft01.AssetID is null or soft02.AssetID is null or soft03.AssetID is null )"

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I misused the brackets

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)